# MemoryError with large .txt file Python when when counting and ranking words

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I'm trying to create a ranked word list csv file from a 500mb text file containing Finnish text. The script will do what I want with small files, but doesn't work for the 500mb beast.

I'm a complete beginner with Python, so forgive me if it's pretty sloppy. From looking around I think I may have to process the file line by line.

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
    # Do something with 'line'
```

I would appreciate any pointers, cheers! My code below:

```
#load text
filename = 'finnish_text.txt'
file = open(filename, 'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()

#lowercase and split words by white space
lowercase = text.lower()
words = lowercase.split()

# remove punctuation from each word
import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in words]

# ranked word count specify return amount here
from collections import Counter
Counter = Counter(stripped)
most_occur = Counter.most_common(100)

# export csv file
import csv
with open('word_rank.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for x in most_occur:
        writer.writerow(x)
```

EDIT:
I ended up using @Bharel 's (what a legend) second solution given in his comment. I had to change a couple of lines due to encoding issues.

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='Latin-1', errors='replace') as file:

with open('word_rank.csv', 'w', newline='', errors='replace') as csvfile:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch everything to generators and it should work:

```
#load text
filename = 'finnish_text.txt'
# Auto-close when done
with open(filename, 'r') as file:

    #lowercase and split words by white space
    word_iterables =(text.lower().split() for line in file)

    # remove punctuation from each word
    import string
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

    stripped = (w.translate(table) for it in word_iterables for w in it)

    # ranked word count specify return amount here
    from collections import Counter
    counter = Counter(stripped)

most_occur = counter.most_common(100)

# export csv file
import csv
with open('word_rank.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for x in most_occur:
        writer.writerow(x)
```

By using generators (parentheses instead of square brackets), the words are all processed lazily instead of being loaded into memory all at once.

---

If you want the most efficient way possible, I've written one as a self-challenge:

```
import itertools
import operator

#load text
filename = 'finnish_text.txt'
# Auto-close when done
with open(filename, 'r') as file:

    # Lowercase the lines
    lower_lines = map(str.lower, file)

    # Split the words in each line - will return [[word, word], [word, word]]
    word_iterables = map(str.split, lower_lines)

    # Combine the iterables:
    # i.e. [[word, word], [word, word]] -> [word, word, word, word]
    words = itertools.chain.from_iterable(word_iterables)

    import string
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

    # remove punctuation from each word
    stripped = map(operator.methodcaller("translate", table), words)

    # ranked word count specify return amount here
    from collections import Counter
    counter = Counter(stripped)

most_occur = counter.most_common(100)

# export csv file
import csv
with open('word_rank.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for x in most_occur:
        writer.writerow(x)
```

It fully utilizes generators written in C (map & itertools).

Comment: Please don't do `Counter = Counter(stripped)`; that makes `Counter` change from being the class to an instance of said class, which is confusing to maintainers who expect it to be the class. PEP8 naming would call for just naming the variable `counter` (assuming no more specific name exists).

Comment: @ShadowRanger oh, didn't notice that. Took it from the OP's code. Thanks mr. Ranger :P

Comment: Why not change from `counter` to something more descriptive like `count_dict`? Granted `Counter` differs from `counter`, but no harm in making it more obvious.

Comment: @jpp that's already up to the OP. I don't wish to mess with his variable names in case he uses them for later code.

Comment: @Bharel, Fair point, it's also good practice (IMO) to mention dubious practices :)

Comment: @jpp It's not a "good" practice, it's a great one :-) I just don't believe it matters so much in this case. `Counter` to `counter` does matter and may cause later bugs so it's quite a must.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Bharel, I used your second given solution. I was getting encoding errors so I added `encoding='Latin-1', errors='replace'`

Comment: What's the etiquette here? Do I edit my original post to show the code I ended up using?

Comment: @Angus well, if you wish, you may add your modified encoding line (no need for the whole code) under a section called "EDIT:" at the bottom of your post, and write that you have used my answer. If my answer has helped you, you're welcome to click on the accepted answer button, according to [stackoverflow's help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). That way other viewers can see the answer you've chosen to use, and any bug you encountered and fixed along the way.